# Deploying on a VPS using the Capistrano gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, vps, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app on a VPS using the capistrano gem. I want to deploy it from  my local machine to the VPS. I'm not using any repositories like Github or SVN.

So, I've installed the capistrano gem and ran 'bundle'. And added the following lines:

Capfile

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p194@gemset'
```

deploy.rb

```
set :user, 'deploy'
set :application, "my_app"

set :scm, :none
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

role :web, '1.2.3.4'
role :app, '1.2.3.4'
role :db,  '1.2.3.4', :primary => true

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

However, after running 'cap deploy:setup' on local, I get the following error:

```
RVM - Capistrano integration was extracted to a separate gem, install: `gem install rvm-capistrano` and remove the `$LOAD_PATH.unshift` line, note also the 'set :rvm_type, :user' is now the default (instead of :system). (RuntimeError)
```

I'm not sure if I should use the rvm-capistrano gem. I'm a total newbie in deployments, detailed or step by step instructions would really help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this? I got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to add

gem "rvm/capistrano"

to your Gemfile and then remove the unshift line (comment out)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about my question. Yup, I did the same thing :)